# How can I divide a single table into multiple tables in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is the problem: I am currently working with a Microsoft Access database that the previous employee created by just adding all the data into one table (yes, all the data into one table). There are about 186 columns in that one table.

I am now responsible for dividing each category of data into its own table. Everything is going fine although progress is too slow. Is there perhaps an SQL command that will somehow divide each category of data into its proper table? As of now I am manually looking at the main table and carefully transferring groups of data into each respective table along with its proper IDs making sure data is not corrupted. Here is the layout I have so far:

[image]

Note: I am probably one of the very few at my campus with database experience.

Comment: I think you are on your own here.  Knowing what data goes with what table seems like it requires a human.

Comment: Yea I thought as much, I'll leave this up for a while though.

Comment: How do you determine what constitutes a group ?

Comment: Make a backup copy of your db file for safekeeping and then try the Table Analyzer Wizard.  It can help you decide how to normalize the existing data.  It's not the final authority, but could be a decent start.  And if it crashes and burns, you still have the backup.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I tried the Table Analyzer Wizard and it is very difficult to work with mainly because the window is not re-size able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this as a classic normalisation process. Your single hugely wide table should contain all of the entities within your domain so as long as you understand the domain you should be able to normalise the structure until you're happy with it.

To create your foreign key lookups run distinct queries against the columns your going to remove and then add the key values back in.

It sounds like you know what you're doing already ? Are you just looking for reassurance that you're on the right track ? (Which it looks like you are).

Good luck though, and enjoy it - it sounds like a good little piece of work.

Comment: I was hoping for a quicker method but classic normalization will do. Confirmation of what I've done thus far helps as well. Thank you!